# How to find spike in data using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have the following schema:

```
SENSOR
--------------
ID (numeric)
READ_DATE (date)
VALUE (numeric)
```

I want to find spikes in data that lasts at least `X` amount of days. We take 1 reading from the sensor only once per day so `ID` and `READ_DATE` are pretty much interchangeable in terms of uniqueness.

For example I have the following records:

```
1, 2019-01-01, 100
2, 2019-01-02, 1000
3, 2019-01-03, 1500
4, 2019-01-04, 1100
5, 2019-01-05, 500
6, 2019-01-06, 700
7, 2019-01-07, 1500
8, 2019-01-08, 2000
```

In this example, for `X = 2` with `VALUE >= 1000`, I want to get row 3, 4, 8 because (2, 3), (3, 4), (7, 8) are consecutively >= to 1000.

I am not sure about how to approach this. I was thinking of doing a `COUNT` window function but don't know how to check whether there are X records >= 1000.

Comment: please tag the dbms being used

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Why not a generic SQL solution?

Comment: the reason i ask is to check if there is an option to use analytic functions.

Comment: Windowed functions aren't available in some RDBMSs (for example), same with `LEAD` and `LAG`, which could be used here

Comment: @RichardHansell: all modern DBMS support window functions today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following:

```
-- this parts helps filtering values < 1000 later on
with a as (
    select *,
    case when value >= 1000 then 1 else 0 end as indicator
    from sensor),
-- using the indicator, create a window that calculates the length of the spike
b as (
    select *,
    sum(indicator) over (order by id asc rows between 2 preceding and current row) as spike
    from a)
-- now filter out all spikes < 3
-- (because the window has a size of 3, it can never be larger than 3, so = 3 is okay)
select id, value from b where spike = 3;
```

This is expanding on @Gordon Linoff's answer, but which I found too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is about as generic as I think this can get.

First I create some data, using a table variable, but this could be a temporary/ physical table:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT, [date] DATE, [value] INT);
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1, '20190101', 100;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 2, '20190102', 1000;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 3, '20190103', 1500;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 4, '20190104', 1100;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 5, '20190105', 500;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 6, '20190106', 700;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 7, '20190107', 1500;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 8, '20190108', 2000;
```

Then I use a CTE (which could be swapped out for a less efficient subquery):

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        CASE WHEN [value] >= 1000 THEN 1 END AS spike
    FROM 
        @table)
SELECT
    x2.id,
    x2.[date],
    x2.[value]
FROM
    x x1
    INNER JOIN x x2 ON x2.id = x1.id + 1
WHERE
    x1.spike = 1
    AND x2.spike = 1;
```

This assumes your ids are sequential, if they aren't you would need to join on date instead, which is trickier.

Results:

```
id  date        value
3   2019-01-03  1500
4   2019-01-04  1100
8   2019-01-08  2000
```

---

Okay, this isn't Postgres, and it isn't very generic (recursive CTE), but it seems to work??

```
DECLARE @spike_length INT = 3;

WITH x AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        CASE WHEN [value] >= 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS spike
    FROM 
        @table),
y AS (
    SELECT
        x.id,
        x.[date],
        x.[value],
        x.spike AS spike_length
    FROM
        x
    WHERE
        id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        x.id,
        x.[date],
        x.[value],
        CASE WHEN x.spike = 0 THEN 0 ELSE y.spike_length + 1 END
    FROM
        y
        INNER JOIN x ON x.id = y.id + 1)
SELECT * FROM y WHERE spike_length >= @spike_length;
```

Results:

```
id  date        value   spike_length
4   2019-01-04  1100    3
```

Comment: But this is assuming X = 2. What if I want X = 20? Seems like that would require 20 joins?

Comment: Yes, I missed that part ;*

Comment: Not that identifiers with `[..]` are invalid standard SQL (and won't work with Postgres)

Comment: Ctrl-H "[" replace with "", same with "]"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use analytic functions, then you should be able to do something like this to get what you need (I altered your 1000 limit to 1500 else it would have brought back all rows which consecutively add up to 1000 and above)

```
    CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id number,
    value number
 );

 insert all
    into test1 (id, value) values (1, 100)
    into test1 (id, value) values (2, 1000)
    into test1 (id, value) values (3, 1500)
    into test1 (id, value) values (4, 1100)
    into test1 (id, value) values (5, 500)
    into test1 (id, value) values (6, 700)
    into test1 (id, value) values (7, 1500)
    into test1 (id, value) values (8, 2000)
select * from dual;
```

EDIT - After re-reading again - and from comment - have re-done to answer the actual question! Using 2 lags - one to make sure previous day was 1000 or greater and another to count up how many times has happened for X filtering.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT id,
        value, 
        spike, 
        CASE WHEN spike = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (spike + LAG(spike, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) + 1) END as SPIKE_LENGTH
    FROM (
        select id,
            value, 
            CASE WHEN LAG(value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) >= 1000 AND value >= 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SPIKE
        from test1
        )
)
WHERE spike_length >= 2;
```

Which returns

```
ID  Value  spike    spike_length
3   1500    1   2
4   1100    1   3
8   2000    1   2
```

If you increase the spike length filter to >= 3 - only get ID 4 which is the only ID with 3 over 1000 in a row.

Comment: Cheers - shouldn't have attempted gone 5pm - for too late to make sense of things ;) Edited

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this as a gaps-and-islands problem -- finding consecutive values above the threshold.  The following gets the first date of such sequences:

```
select s.read_date
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from sensor s
      where value >= 1000
     ) s
group by (date - seqnum * interval '1 day')
having count(*) >= 2;
```

The observation here is that `(date - seqnum * interval '1 day')` is constant for rows that are adjacent.

You can get the original rows with one more layer of subqueries:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*, count(*) over (partition by (date - seqnum * interval '1 day') as cnt
      from (select s.*,
                   row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
            from sensor s
            where value >= 1000
           ) s
     ) s
where cnt >= 2;
```